# Selfhosted web api route to angularJS index.html

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I use OWIN to selfhost (I'm not using IIS) my web api and I was reading a lot about web applications based on asp.net web api and angularJS. In most examples there where a default route of the api like

```
HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(_baseAddress);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But I don't understand where the route to the index.html file of the angularJS frontend happens? I know how to get data when I'm calling an api request like `api/person/5`. But which part of the code is responsible to route any unspecified api request to the main page of angularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Using WebAPI and a default route to Index.html is not a good idea. Because the calling would be `yourapp.com/api/xxxx`

Instead since you are using IIS (I assume you arent using OWIN to selfhost).In IIS you can and should set a default page.

This way your url will just look ile `yourapp.com` regardless of it being `index.html`, `jack.html`, or `test.html`

To answer your question  **But which part of the code is responsible to route any unspecified api request to the main page of angularJS?**

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Main" });
});
```

use `$routeprovider.otherwise` to do the redirct. If you send an non-identifiable route to angular the otherwise config value will redirect you to your `main` in this instance.

This [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615(v=ws.10).aspx) page will walk you through setting up a default page in iis

Comment: I use OWIN to selfhost. I will edit my question to make that clear. Sorry. Where would I set the default page when I'm using IIS? Thats why I can't find any route to index.html in these examples. Anyway, how can I do that with OWIN?

Comment: When I ment self hosting with OWIN, i was referring to not using IIS and using apache or something.

Comment: I'm not using IIS. I'm completely decoupled from IIS.

Comment: @cpa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478222/how-to-set-default-static-web-page-for-katana-owin-self-hosted-app I would try this then.